# Error stringifying an object when calling Custom Action in OData D365 Online

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, odata

I have created a custom action that takes in an input parameter called `paramsInput` (string).

I want to send to said action a stringified JSON object so that it may be deserialized inside the action.

Snippet of action code:

```cs
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    try
    {
        _context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
        IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        _crmService = factory.CreateOrganizationService(_context.UserId);
    
        string paramsInput = _context.InputParameters.Contains("paramsInput") ? _context.InputParameters["paramsInput"].ToString() : string.Empty;
    
        if (paramsInput != string.Empty)
        {
            // Deserialize to concrete class
            InputParams inputParameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InputParams>(paramsInput);
    
            // logic here...       
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle exception...
    }
}
```

I have also created a generic function that receives the action's name and the parameters to send and calls the action via OData:

```cs
public bool CallMessage(string action, JObject parameters, out string reason)
{
    RegenerateAccess(); // Microsoft Online
    string urlAPI = "/api/data/v9.1/" + action;
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_serviceUrl);
        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);  //2 minutes  
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, urlAPI);
    
        /*StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
        using (JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
        {
            writer.QuoteChar = '\'';
    
            JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
            ser.Serialize(writer, parameters);
        }*/
    
    
        var jsonObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);
        //request.Content = new StringContent(sb.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        request.Content = new StringContent(jsonObj, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
    
        //Set the access token
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _authResult.AccessToken);
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
        reason = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                
        return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }
}
```

My issue is that I'm getting a `Bad Request 400` back, and the response reads - `Microsoft.OData.ODataException: An unexpected 'StartObject' node was found for property named 'paramsInput' when reading from the JSON reader. A 'PrimitiveValue' node was expected.`

My parameters JObject is structured as follows:

```json
{
    "paramsInput" : {
            "id" : "xxxx-xxxx...", // some guid
            "code" : 1 // int
    }
}
```

or via code:

```cs
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
JObject parameters = new JObject();
parameters.Add("id", guid);
parameters.Add("code", 1);
JObject wrapper = new JObject();
wrapper.Add("paramsInput", parameters);
    
// send wrapper JObject to CallMessage
```

I don't want to change the structure of CallMessage function as it is a generic function that may be used multiple times by other sources.

Comment: Could you make progress with your issue?

Answer (score 1):

The action's parameter `paramsInput` (containing the JSON) is a `string` parameter. Therefore, when this parameter is constructed, it must be stringified and your last code snippet would need to look like this:

```cs
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
JObject parameters = new JObject();
parameters.Add("id", guid);
parameters.Add("code", 1);
JObject wrapper = new JObject();
wrapper.Add("paramsInput", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters));
    
// send wrapper JObject to CallMessage
```

A few side notes:

1. you decided to create your code executing Dataverse actions from scratch using `HttpClient`, which in itself is fine, but doing so you need to do all plumbing yourself. Another option would be to use the `OrganizationRequest` from the MS SDK libraries.
2. The Action is a bit of legacy nowadays and has been replaced by the Custom API. A Custom API pretty much works in the same way and as a bonus you do not need to create custom plugin steps.

Answer (score 0):

Henk's answer is correct, You told the API to accept a string, thus you must send it the serialized version of your JSON in the string parameter.

I cannot add a comment to Henk's answer due to length restrictions, but I wanted to add a point of clarification here:

> The Action is a bit of legacy nowadays and has been replaced by the Custom API. A Custom API pretty much works in the same way and as a bonus you do not need to create custom plugin steps.

You don't need to create a plugin supporting it if you're going to process it somewhere else ( Like PowerAutomate).   This is technically called an "Event" in the Power Platform.  You also don't need to create a plugin to support a custom action.

The fundamental difference is that "Custom Action" was implemented as a Workflow Operation, where "CustomAPI" is not.  You gain a bit of perf as the system does not need to invoke the workflow runtime to run your operation.

Originally, 'Custom Action' was intended to be used as a custom workflow implementation (Think the way you use an HTTP trigger for PowerAutomate today.)  However, folks quickly realized that you could wire up a Plugin to the SDK message to get it to act like a 'custom api' inside Dataverse.

Carrying that forward, the CustomAPI Definition is used for both Events and Custom Operations.

As Henk Said,  'Custom Action' is the older process for creating a callable interface for this.

Comment: It is true that a plugin is not required when implementing an action. However, from the very start actions were implemented using two distinct approaches: 1) by a plugin, 2) by a code activity called from the action's process definition. It is a matter of taste which one to choose, but personally I have never been a fan of workflows and always avoided them whenever possible.